# Xamarin Forms devexpress grid - access cell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress

I'm using Xamarin Forms with devexpress grid, which contains multiple rows.
I'd like to be able to get the value of a selected row / cell. How can I achieve this?

```
<ScrollView>
    <dxGrid:GridControl 
        x:Name="grid" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding materials}"
        AutoFilterPanelVisibility="true"
        IsReadOnly="true"
        SortMode="Multiple">
            <dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxGrid:TextColumn 
                    FieldName="id" 
                    Caption = "ID" 
                    AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
                <dxGrid:TextColumn 
                    FieldName="description" 
                    Caption = "Material" 
                    AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
            </dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxGrid:GridControl>
</ScrollView>
```

materials is a simple List, where Material is a simple example class, containing two string properties (id, description).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/Xamarin/DevExpress.Mobile.DataGrid.GridControl.Class.properties), you can bind the property [`SelectedRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/Xamarin/DevExpress.Mobile.DataGrid.GridControl.SelectedRowHandle.property) to recover the selected row:

> When an end-user taps a data row in the grid, this row becomes selected. Use the SelectedRowHandle property to obtain or set a row currently selected in the grid. The SelectedDataObject property returns an object that specifies a data source record to which the row selected in the grid corresponds. After the grid's selection is changed, the SelectionChanged event occurs.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Well, I got the binding to selectedRowHandle working, but I can't get access the object.

Comment: I'm now out of my PC where I have Xamarin installed but I think that you should get the object with `materials[selectedRow]`, selectedRow is for example the name of the property that you have binded to `SelectedRowHandle`

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the selectedrow adjusts when I filter the grid, so I can't use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself:

```
<ScrollView>
    <dxGrid:GridControl 
        x:Name="grid" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding materials}"
        AutoFilterPanelVisibility="true"
        IsReadOnly="true"
        SortMode="Multiple"
        SelectedRowHandle="{Binding selectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedDataObject="{Binding selectedRowObject, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxGrid:TextColumn 
                FieldName="description" 
                Caption = "Material" 
                AutoFilterCondition="Contains"/>
            </dxGrid:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxGrid:GridControl>
    </ScrollView>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
private int SelectedRow;
public int selectedRow
    {
        set
        {
            if(SelectedRow != value)
            {
                SelectedRow = value;
                if(PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selectedRow"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return SelectedRow;
        }
    }

    private Object SelectedRowObject;
    public Object selectedRowObject
    {
        set
        {
            if (SelectedRowObject != value)
            {
                SelectedRowObject = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selectedRowObject"));
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selectedRowDescription"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return SelectedRowObject;
        }
    }

    private String SelectedRowDescription;
    public String selectedRowDescription
    {
        get
        {
            if(SelectedRowObject != null && SelectedRowObject is Material)
            {
                Material mat = (Material)SelectedRowObject;
                return mat.description;
            } else
            {
                return "-";
            }
        }
    }
```